# Use Type with Flutter Hooks

Tags: flutter, hook

I was trying to add different useState in my page with Flutter hook but i can't find a way to do it by giving them a type first, because of the inital value requested.

i can't initialize my useState with :

`QRViewController? controller = useState();`

or

`final controller = useState<QRViewController>()`

or

`QRViewController? controller = useState(null);`

How can i initialized controller with custom type ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
final ValueNotifier<QRViewController?> controller = useState(null);
```

Or

```
final controller = useState<QRViewController?>(null);
```

You were very close.

Comment: indeed, thanks man !